# MapView detect scrolling

Tags: ios, uiview, mapkit

I'm wishing that `MKMapView` inherited from `UIScrollView` just like `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` are. This way you can override the `UIScrollView` delegate methods and do what you need to do.

I've found the method of attaching a pan gesture to the `MapView` like so:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* mapPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapPanGestureHandler:)];
[mapPanGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:mapPanGestureRecognizer];
```

This works fairly well except for the fact that the `mapView` has a deceleration element to it. For example if you're in mid scroll and lift your finger, the map keeps going and slows down then eventually stops.

What I'm doing is rendering some offscreen annotations in an overlay on top of my map (another `UIView`) using core graphics. It's working great except for the deceleration problem.

All I need to know is that the map has moved. The parameters I need I can query straight from the map itself.

Has anyone found a technique to get callbacks while decelerating? I mean I suppose I could use a timer when the gesture ends to fire repeatedly for a half a second or so.

Comment: Do you need to know that the map is moving while it's moving, or only when it stops moving?

Comment: While it's moving, whether or not a finger is touching it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MKMapView` doesn't have analogous delegate callback to `UIScrollView`, so you're going to need to improvise.

> Has anyone found a technique to get callbacks while decelerating? I mean I suppose I could use a timer when the gesture ends to fire repeatedly for a half a second or so.

If you're wanting to accurately keep views in sync with the map's movement, you'll be better off using `CADisplayLink` because you'll get a callback after each screen refresh. On the other hand, if you use a timer, the callbacks won't necessarily align with the refresh rate and you may see artifacts.

You'd set it up like this:

```
CADisplayLink *link = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateViewsBasedOnMapRegion:)];
[link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

And then handle the callback like this:

```
- (void)updateViewsBasedOnMapRegion:(CADisplayLink *)link
{
    // update whatever it is you need to update
}
```

You could use this exclusively and discard the gesture recognizer or keep the gesture recognizer and pause the link when not needed.

Comment: Great. I can't wait to give that a try in the morning. I agree that the Timer solution is hokey, but as you said... improvise. I had the thought use KVO on the MapView.region property. I'm not sure how often the map actually updates it's region variable though. I will try both. Thanks

Comment: CADisplayLink solved the problem for me. I replaced the pan gesture and it's target selector with the code in this post. It works flawlessly, deceleration and all.

Answer (score 0):

The [`MKMapViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) protocol defines `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` that will be called when the region displayed by the map changes. It gets call repeatedly while the map is scrolling -

> **Discussion** This method is called whenever the currently displayed map
>   region changes. During scrolling, this method may be called many times
>   to report updates to the map position. Therefore, your implementation
>   of this method should be as lightweight as possible to avoid affecting
>   scrolling performance.

You should be able to use this method to access the new map region and redraw your overlay (or if the re-draw is time-consuming you could dispatch a task on another thread to redraw the overlay)

Comment: `regionDidChangeAnimated` only gets called occasionally. For example, if you pan across the entire screen, it may only get called once or twice. From the question, I gather that he's looking for more frequent updates.

Comment: Then perhaps combining the current approach of the gesture recogniser and the delegate method - the gesture recogniser will capture the majority of the movement as it is now and the delegate for the final update after deceleration

Comment: Timothy is correct. That method is called very infrequently. I my testing it would only get called once the deceleration stops. It's sister method "willChange" is called only once as well. I'm looking for something that will be called enough to fluidly render object on the map as it moves.

Comment: Can't you just use an MKAnnotationView and render your overlay into that?

Comment: You could if you are using MKAnnotations, but in my case I was using a UICollectionView overlay on the map as a guide to where off screen annotations were located. Lots of time has passed since this post else I'd give more specifics

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** just you should use from following code. after scroll following overrided method will be called. also you can detect amount of scroll with `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake` like bellow.

```
extension UIViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) { 
       let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.region.center.latitude, mapView.region.center.longitude) 
    }
}
```