# MKMapView constantly monitor heading

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, key-value-observing

I'm rendering some content in a layer that sits on top of my `MKMapView`. The whole thing works great with the exception of rotation. When a user rotates the map I need to be able to rotate what I'm rendering in my own layer.

The standard answer I found is to use:

```
NSLog(@"heading: %f", self.mapView.camera.heading");
```

The issue with this is that the content of the heading variable only updates when the pinch/rotate gesture is ending, not during the gesture. I need much more frequent updates.

There is no heading property on the **mapView** itself.

I thought maybe using **KVO** like such:

```
    // Somewhere in setup
    [self.mapView.camera addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"heading" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];


    // KVO Callback
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                         ofObject:(id)object
                           change:(NSDictionary *)change
                          context:(void *)context{

        if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"heading"]){
            // New value
        }
    }
```

However the **KVO** listener never fires which isn't surprising.

Is there a method that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: In iOS11 this is solved using mapviewdidchangevisibleregion 
 see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/2998428-mapviewdidchangevisibleregion?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer, which you could adapt (using `CADisplayLink`):

[MapView detect scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122173/mapview-detect-scrolling)

Comment: That's actually one of my posts. The problem is not with rendering, it's with querying the heading rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to exist indeed no way to track the simply read the current heading while rotation the map. Since I just implemented a compass view that rotates with the map, I want to share my knowledge with you.

I explicitly invite you to refine this answer. Since I have a deadline, I'm satisfied as it is now (before that, the compass was only set in the moment the map stopped to rotate) but there is room for improvement and finetuning.

I uploaded a sample project here: [MapRotation Sample Project](http://ryux51.net/MapRotation.zip)

Okay, let's start. Since I assume you all use Storyboards nowadays, drag a few gesture recognizers to the map. (Those who don't surely knows how to convert these steps into written lines.)

To detect map rotation, zoom and 3D angle we need a rotation, a pan and a pinch gesture recognizer.
[image: Drag Gesture Recognizers on the MapView]

Disable "Delays touches ended" for the Rotation Gesture Recognizer...
[image: Disable "Delays touches ended" for the Rotation Gesture Recognizer]

... and increase "Touches" to 2 for the Pan Gesture Recognizer.
[image: Increase "Touches" to 2 for the Pan Gesture Recognizer]

Set the delegate of these 3 to the containing view controller.
[image: Ctrl-drag to the containing view controller...]
[image: ... and set the delegate.]

Drag for all 3 gesture recognizers the Referencing Outlet Collections to the MapView and select "gestureRecognizers"

[image]

Now Ctrl-drag the rotation gesture recognizer to the implementation as Outlet like this:

> ```
> @IBOutlet var rotationGestureRecognizer: UIRotationGestureRecognizer!
> ```

and all 3 recognizers as IBAction:

> ```
> @IBAction func handleRotation(sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
>     ...
> }
>
> @IBAction func handleSwipe(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
>     ...
> }
>
> @IBAction func pinchGestureRecognizer(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

Yes, I named the pan gesture "handleSwype". It's explained below. :)

Listed below the complete code for the controller that of course also has to implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol.
I tried to be very detailed in the comments.

```
// compassView is the container View,
// arrowImageView is the arrow which will be rotated
@IBOutlet weak var compassView: UIView!
var arrowImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Compass")!)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    compassView.addSubview(arrowImageView)
}

// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// Helper: Detect when the MapView changes                                                  *

private func mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction() -> Bool {
    let view = mapView!.subviews[0]
    // Look through gesture recognizers to determine whether this region
    // change is from user interaction
    if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
            if( recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began ||
                recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended ) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************



// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// Helper: Needed to be allowed to recognize gestures simultaneously to the MapView ones.   *

func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************



// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// Helper: Use CADisplayLink to fire a selector at screen refreshes to sync with each       *
// frame of MapKit's animation

private var displayLink : CADisplayLink!

func setUpDisplayLink() {
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "refreshCompassHeading:")
    displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************





// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// Detect if the user starts to interact with the map...                                    *

private var mapChangedFromUserInteraction = false

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    
    mapChangedFromUserInteraction = mapViewRegionDidChangeFromUserInteraction()
    
    if (mapChangedFromUserInteraction) {
        
        // Map interaction. Set up a CADisplayLink.
        setUpDisplayLink()
    }
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// ... and when he stops.                                                                   *

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    
    if mapChangedFromUserInteraction {
        
        // Final transform.
        // If all calculations would be correct, then this shouldn't be needed do nothing.
        // However, if something went wrong, with this final transformation the compass
        // always points to the right direction after the interaction is finished.
        // Making it a 500 ms animation provides elasticity und prevents hard transitions.
        
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.arrowImageView.transform =
                CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * -mapView.camera.heading) / 180.0)
        })
        
        
        
        // You may want this here to work on a better rotate out equation. :)
        
        let stoptime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        print("Needed time to rotate out:", stoptime - startRotateOut, "with velocity",
            remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded, ".")
        print("Velocity decrease per sec:", (Double(remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded)
            / (stoptime - startRotateOut)))
        
        
        
        // Clean up for the next rotation.
        
        remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded = 0
        initialMapGestureModeIsRotation = nil
        if let _ = displayLink {
            displayLink.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************





// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// This is our main function. The display link calls it once every display frame.           *

// The moment the user let go of the map.
var startRotateOut = NSTimeInterval(0)

// After that, if there is still momentum left, the velocity is > 0.
// The velocity of the rotation gesture in radians per second.
private var remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded = CGFloat(0)

// We need some values from the last frame
private var prevHeading = CLLocationDirection()
private var prevRotationInRadian = CGFloat(0)
private var prevTime = NSTimeInterval(0)

// The momentum gets slower ower time
private var currentlyRemainingVelocity = CGFloat(0)

func refreshCompassHeading(sender: AnyObject) {
    
    // If the gesture mode is not determinated or user is adjusting pitch
    // we do obviously nothing here. :)
    if initialMapGestureModeIsRotation == nil || !initialMapGestureModeIsRotation! {
        return
    }
    

    let rotationInRadian : CGFloat
    
    if remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded == 0 {
        
        // This is the normal case, when the map is beeing rotated.
        rotationInRadian = rotationGestureRecognizer.rotation
        
    } else {
        
        // velocity is > 0 or < 0.
        // This is the case when the user ended the gesture and there is
        // still some momentum left.
        
        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        let deltaTime = currentTime - prevTime
        
        // Calculate new remaining velocity here.
        // This is only very empiric and leaves room for improvement.
        // For instance I noticed that in the middle of the translation
        // the needle rotates a bid faster than the map.
        let SLOW_DOWN_FACTOR : CGFloat = 1.87
        let elapsedTime = currentTime - startRotateOut

        // Mathematicians, the next line is for you to play.
        currentlyRemainingVelocity -=
            currentlyRemainingVelocity * CGFloat(elapsedTime)/SLOW_DOWN_FACTOR
        
        
        let rotationInRadianSinceLastFrame =
        currentlyRemainingVelocity * CGFloat(deltaTime)
        rotationInRadian = prevRotationInRadian + rotationInRadianSinceLastFrame
        
        // Remember for the next frame.
        prevRotationInRadian = rotationInRadian
        prevTime = currentTime
    }
    
    // Convert radian to degree and get our long-desired new heading.
    let rotationInDegrees = Double(rotationInRadian * (180 / CGFloat(M_PI)))
    let newHeading = -mapView!.camera.heading + rotationInDegrees
    
    // No real difference? No expensive transform then.
    let difference = abs(newHeading - prevHeading)
    if difference < 0.001 {
        return
    }

    // Finally rotate the compass.
    arrowImageView.transform =
        CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * newHeading) / 180.0)

    // Remember for the next frame.
    prevHeading = newHeading
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************



// As soon as this optional is set the initial mode is determined.
// If it's true than the map is in rotation mode,
// if false, the map is in 3D position adjust mode.

private var initialMapGestureModeIsRotation : Bool?



// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// UIRotationGestureRecognizer                                                              *

@IBAction func handleRotation(sender: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if (initialMapGestureModeIsRotation == nil) {
        initialMapGestureModeIsRotation = true
    } else if !initialMapGestureModeIsRotation! {
        // User is not in rotation mode.
        return
    }
    
    
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        if sender.velocity != 0 {

            // Velocity left after ending rotation gesture. Decelerate from remaining
            // momentum. This block is only called once.
            remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded = sender.velocity
            currentlyRemainingVelocity = remainingVelocityAfterUserInteractionEnded
            startRotateOut = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
            prevTime = startRotateOut
            prevRotationInRadian = rotationGestureRecognizer.rotation
        }
    }
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *
// Yes, there is also a SwypeGestureRecognizer, but the length for being recognized as      *
// is far too long. Recognizing a 2 finger swype up or down with a PanGestureRecognizer
// yields better results.

@IBAction func handleSwipe(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    // After a certain altitude is reached, there is no pitch possible.
    // In this case the 3D perspective change does not work and the rotation is initialized.
    // Play with this one.
    let MAX_PITCH_ALTITUDE : Double = 100000
    
    // Play with this one for best results detecting a swype. The 3D perspective change is
    // recognized quite quickly, thats the reason a swype recognizer here is of no use.
    let SWYPE_SENSITIVITY : CGFloat = 0.5 // play with this one
    
    if let _ = initialMapGestureModeIsRotation {
        // Gesture mode is already determined.
        // Swypes don't care us anymore.
        return
    }
    
    if mapView?.camera.altitude > MAX_PITCH_ALTITUDE {
        // Altitude is too high to adjust pitch.
        return
    }
    
    
    let panned = sender.translationInView(mapView)
    
    if fabs(panned.y) > SWYPE_SENSITIVITY {
        // Initial swype up or down.
        // Map gesture is most likely a 3D perspective correction.
        initialMapGestureModeIsRotation = false
    }
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************
//                                                                                          *

@IBAction func pinchGestureRecognizer(sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    // pinch is zoom. this always enables rotation mode.
    if (initialMapGestureModeIsRotation == nil) {
        initialMapGestureModeIsRotation = true
        // Initial pinch detected. This is normally a zoom
        // which goes in hand with a rotation.
    }
}
//                                                                                          *
// ******************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Sorry you can't find a way. I did create my own compass view for a different app. I am using CoreLocation to get heading updates and then rendering the view that way. Would that work for you?

Comment: Huh? Did I expressed myself so badly? This answer describes the workaround that I found and it works quite nicely.
I rephrased the first segment. :)

And yes, I'm also using CoreLocation for the compass mode "internal compass" (I excluded it from my code above since this has nothing to do with your question). The compass I implemented in this answer points to the north point of the map while rotating it.

Comment: I added a sample project to the answer for all those who want to peek at an already working code.

Comment: @RyuX51 - great job, thanks for taking the time to post this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a `nil` context, pass a value to compare with on you **KVO** observer, like this:

`static void *CameraContext= &CameraContext;`

```
    // Somewhere in setup
    [self.mapView.camera addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"heading" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:CameraContext];


// KVO Callback
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context{

 if (context == CameraContext) {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"heading"]){
        // New value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested. That got the KVO callback to fire once (at startup (initial) with a value of -0, whatever that means), but it never fires while I rotate the map. I'm not surprised as MKMapCamera is not key value coding compliant (at least it's not stated in the documentation).

Comment: While you rotate it doesn't fire, but when you finish rotating does it fire?

Comment: No, it only fires once ever. Around create time.

Comment: Isn't your self.mapView.camera object being released somewhere or you're removing it as an observer?

Comment: No. self.mapView.camera is an iVar which is set near init. The observer is never removed by me. Have you tried this? Do you have it working?

Comment: the camera property is copy so this won't work, observing the keypath @"camera.heading" of the mapView might though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior in a MapKit program for OS X. I'm using the `<MKMapViewDelegate>` call `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` instead of a KVO notification on changes to `heading`, but I'm still only seeing the call at the end of rotations.

I just tried implementing `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`. That does in fact get called at the beginning of rotations. Perhaps you could begin polling the region upon receipt of `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:`, cease polling on `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`, and in between do whatever critical updates you need during the rotations.