# Is it possible to use KVO to track changes to the `MKMapView.camera.heading` property?

Tags: ios, mapkit, key-value-observing

I am trying to track changes to the map orientation using the camera heading property.

```
// Register for notifications of changes to camera
if let camera = self.mapView?.camera {
    self.camera = camera
    camera.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "heading", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: &MapViewController.myContext)
}
```

...

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == &MapViewController.myContext {
        if keyPath == "heading" {
            if let heading = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CLLocationDirection {
                self.heading = heading
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

Comment: This thread may possibly help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139475/mkmapview-constantly-monitor-heading

Answer (score 0):

The camera property mode is copy so you are not observing the current camera instance just one that was copied when you called the getter. You need to observe key path of `@"camera.heading"` or `@"camera"` on the map view and hope that a new camera object is set internally when the heading changes.